# Scroll to specific slide when clicked instead of previous and next

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 4 buttons and I want to assign them to each slide. There are 4 slides. If each button is clicked it should scroll to the specified slide assigned to it, and so now. How do I achieve this?

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";
import "./App.css";

const Slide = ({ slide, current, handleSlideClick }) => {
  const slideRef = useRef();

  let classNames = "slide";

  if (current === slide.index) classNames += " slide--current";
  else if (current - 1 === slide.index) classNames += " slide--previous";
  else if (current + 1 === slide.index) classNames += " slide--next";

  return (
    <li
      ref={slideRef}
      className={classNames}
      onClick={() => handleSlideClick(slide.index)}
    >
      <div className="slide__image-wrapper">
        <img className="slide__image" alt={slide.headline} src={slide.src} />
      </div>

      <article className="slide__content">
        <h2 className="slide__headline">{slide.headline}</h2>
        <button className="slide__action btn">{slide.button}</button>
      </article>
    </li>
  );
};

const Slider = ({ slides, heading }) => {
  const [current, setCurrent] = useState(0);

  const handlePreviousClick = () => {
    const previous = current - 1;
    setCurrent(previous < 0 ? slides.length - 1 : previous);
  };

  const handleNextClick = () => {
    const next = current + 1;
    setCurrent(next === slides.length ? 0 : next);
  };

  const handleSlideClick = (index) => {
    if (current !== index) {
      setCurrent(index);
    }
  };

  const wrapperTransform = {
    transform: `translateX(-${current * (100 / slides.length)}%)`
  };

  return (
    <div className="slider">
      <ul className="slider__wrapper" style={wrapperTransform}>
        {slides.map((slide) => (
          <Slide
            key={slide.index}
            slide={slide}
            current={current}
            handleSlideClick={handleSlideClick}
          />
        ))}
      </ul>

      <div className="slider__controls">
        <button onClick={handlePreviousClick}>1</button>
        <button onClick={handleNextClick}>2</button>
        <button onClick={handlePreviousClick}>3</button>
        <button onClick={handleNextClick}>4</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );

return <Slider slides={slideData} />;
};
```

Tried simplifying the `Slider` function like this but no luck.

```
const Slider = ({ slides, slideRef }) => {
  const [current, setCurrent] = useState(0);

  const handleSlideChange = (swiper) => {
    setCurrent(swiper.realIndex);
  };

  const handleSlideClick = (index) => {
    if (slideRef.current) {
      slideRef.current.swiper.slideTo(index);
      setCurrent(index);
    }
  };

  const wrapperTransform = {
    transform: `translateX(-${current * (100 / slides.length)}%)`
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of "previous" and "next" buttons you have a button for each slide, so when each button is pressed they should all call the same callback and pass their "slide index" to set the `current` state value.

Example:

```
const Slider = ({ slides, heading }) => {
  const [current, setCurrent] = useState(0);

  const clickHandler = index => () => { // NOTE: this is a curried function
    setCurrent(index);
  };

  const handleSlideClick = (index) => {
    if (current !== index) {
      setCurrent(index);
    }
  };

  const wrapperTransform = {
    transform: `translateX(-${current * (100 / slides.length)}%)`
  };

  return (
    <div className="slider">
      <ul className="slider__wrapper" style={wrapperTransform}>
        {slides.map((slide) => (
          <Slide
            key={slide.index}
            slide={slide}
            current={current}
            handleSlideClick={handleSlideClick}
          />
        ))}
      </ul>

      <div className="slider__controls">
        <button onClick={clickHandler(0)}>1</button>
        <button onClick={clickHandler(1)}>2</button>
        <button onClick={clickHandler(2)}>3</button>
        <button onClick={clickHandler(3)}>4</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```